# Циркулярный буфер на PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Хочется табличку с ограничением по занимаемому месту на диске.

Вроде capped collection от mongodb.

Есть идея партицировать по времени и каждый день удалять с первой партиции.

Но может готовые есть?

Comment: как вариант, можно просто трегер на добавление... но эффективность всего этого будет не огонь...

Comment: @Fat-Zer - десятки гигов туда писать хочу. триггер вообщем не вариант.